# Laravel Backpack only show column if it's data belongs to authenticated user

Tags: laravel

I have a table where I only want to show the user's own posts - or one's to which they've contributed. But each post can have many collaborators, so it's a has many & belongs to many relationship.

```
User has many posts
Post belongs to many users
```

I want to do something like this:

`$PostsBelongingToUser = backpack_auth()->user()->posts`

And I ONLY want to show data from $PostsBelongingToUser on the CRUD table that is generated by backpack. How do I do that?

Comment: You have ManyToMany relationship here, so  when you call $user->posts it gives you only the posts of that user

Comment: I'm aware of that. I'd just like to know how I can tell backpack to use data from the user()->posts relationship. My crud revolves around the posts model and not the users model.